# multiple views in binding adapter

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a button. When the button is clicked, the button and a textView are animated. The question is: how to get multiple views on the binding adapter? Is the way I did it correct?

```
<variable
    name="variableTextViewDescription"
    type="androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView" />
```

```
fun bind(task: Task, viewModel: ToDoListViewModel) {
            binding.task = task
            binding.viewModel = viewModel
            binding.variableTextViewDescription = binding.textViewDescription
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
```

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["task", "textViewDescription"], requireAll = true)
fun ImageButton.setOnClickButtonMore(task: Task, textViewDescription: AppCompatTextView) {

    if (task.isExpanded) {
        toggleArrow(this, false, textViewDescription)
    } else {
        toggleArrow(this, true, textViewDescription)
    }

    this.setOnClickListener {
        task.isExpanded = toggleArrow(it, task.isExpanded, textViewDescription)
    }

}
```

```
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:task="@{task}"
                    app:textViewDescription="@{variableTextViewDescription}"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a solution for you, that maybe different from adding multiple Views to the same Binding Adapter.

You can add **a MutableLiveData** when changed by Button click, it starts the animation.

So, we will have a single MutableLiveData added to **2 Binding Adapters** (the button binding adapter and the ImageView binding adapter).

when the value of the MutableLiveData changed, both binding adapters will **fire** and in both adapters load your animation.

Comment: I made both adapters that take boolean values, but I don't know how to correctly implement a MutableLiveData in this context. Can you show me an example?

Comment: What he meant was , you should add a MutableLiveData Boolean to your viewModel , and not the adapter. You can observe this live data in your fragment/activity and change its value via the binding adapter.